# Order_by in sqlalchemy with outer join

Tags: python, mysql, join, sqlalchemy, outer-join

I have the following sqlalchemy queries:

```
score = Scores.query.group_by(Scores.email).order_by(Scores.date).subquery()
students = db.session.query(Students, score.c.id).filter_by(archive=0).order_by(Students.exam_date).outerjoin(score, Students.email == score.c.email)
```

And then I render the things with:

```
return render_template('students.html', students=students.all())
```

Now, the issue is that I want the last score for a student to be displayed, as there are many of them corresponding to each user. But the first one seems to be returned. I tried some sortings and order_by on the first query, score, but without success.

How can I affect and pick only one latest  result from the "score" to be paired with the corresponding row in "students"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you want to make sure that the subquery selects only rows for a particular student. You do that with the [`correlate`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html?highlight=correlate#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.correlate) method:

```
score = db.session.query(Scores.id).order_by(Scores.date.desc()).correlate(Students)
```

This alone does nothing, as you do not access the students. The idea of `correlate` is that if you use `Students` on your subquery, it will *not* add it to the `FROM` list but instead rely on the outer query providing it. Now you will want to refine your query (the join condition if you wish):

```
score = score.filter(Students.email == Scores.email)
```

This will produce a subquery that each time only returns the score for a single student. The remaining question is, if each student has to multiple scores. If so, you need to limit it (if there isn't, you don't need the `order_by` part from above as well):

```
score = score.limit(1)
```

Now you have made sure your query returns a single scalar value. Since you are using the query in a select context you will want to turn it into a scalar value:

```
students = db.session.query(Students, score.as_scalar()).filter_by(archive=0).order_by(Students.exam_date)
```

The `as_scalar` method is a way of telling SQLAlchemy that this returns a **single row and column**. Because otherwise you could not put it into a select.

*Note*: I am not 100% sure you need that `limit` if you put `as_scalar`. Try it out and expirment. If each student has only one score anyway then you don't need to worry at all about any of that stuff.

A little hint on the way: A `Query` instance is by itself an iterable. That means as long as you don't print it or similar, you can pass around a query just like a list with the only exception that will really only run on access (lazy) and that you can dynamically refine it, e.g. you could slice it: `students[:10]` would only select the first 10 students (and if you do it on the query it will execute it as a `LIMIT` instead of slicing a list, where the former is much more efficient).

Comment: Well, thank you very much!

This resolved my issue. I noticed one small bug, in the filter() function, "==" is needed instead of "=", single equals goes with filter_by() so you probably miswrote that.

I also added .desc() method to order_by(), which gave the the correct one :) (I have tried this with original code as well, no success)